# pytest: How to collect tests which were failed in earlier run

Tags: selenium, pytest

I am using pytest for selenium tests.
Is there any way to manipulate collected tests, skip the tests that were pass in earlier run.
Consider me a newbie in pytest.

Comment: I think you can make it manually only using `pytest.mark` fixtures, like `@pytest.mark.skip()`. To get full list of available mark-fixtures try `pytest --markers` in `cmd`/`Terminal`

Comment: But if you have your test results in convinient format you can try to write `test_is_pass` condition and to use `@pytest.mark.skipif(test_is_pass)` fixture to make it automatically

Answer (score 0):

Use the `--lf`/`--last-failed` option, see [the docs](http://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/cache.html)